# Partial Derivative using the chain rule?

Tags: calculus

How to obtain the partial derivative of this parametric function using the chain rule? Specifically, I want to find
$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}=-3 \text{ and } \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}=2$$
$$f: \left(\begin{array}{c}x \\ y \end{array} \right)=
\left(\begin{array}{c}3 \\ -4 \end{array}\right)
+t\left(\begin{array}{c}2 \\ 3 \end{array}\right)
$$
I know how to convert the function into standard form, getting $-3x+2y+17=0$ and then getting the 2 partial derivatives. I suppose I know how to get $df/dt = \left(\begin{array}{c}2 \\ 3 \end{array}\right)$ or $dx/dt = 2$ and $dy/dt=3$, but I can't seem to arrange any of these to get $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}=-3.$
When a parametric function is defined in a single variable, $t,$ it does not have a partial derivative, there being no second variable, $s,$ to hold constant.  So while the function, $f,$ has output in $\mathbb{R}^2,$ its input is in $\mathbb{R}.$ When the function is defined without the parameter, as $-3x+2y=-17,$ then the input is in $\mathbb{R}^2$ and the concept of a partial derivative is meaningful.

Comment: But what is f at you partial derivative $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$ ? It doesn't make sense to me. You have an equation with $x$ and $y$.

Comment: @callculus42 f is the function in two variables x(t) and y(t).

Comment: If you define $f(x,y)=-3x+2y+17$ then $$f(x,y)=0 \iff \begin{pmatrix}x\\y\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}3\\-4\end{pmatrix}+\begin{pmatrix}2\\3\end{pmatrix}t\quad\text{ for some }t.$$
But as it is, your question makes no sense.

Comment: @Ali I agree that the question makes no sense.  I was attempting to use a partial derivative  to obtain a normal  to a line in 3d, without having to compute a point on the line.  Note that i do mean a line, not a curve, unless we define a line in 3d as curve.  TNB doesn't really work because the derivatives disappear, there being no curvature..  Perhaps i should erase the question.